# jQuery and JSON: getting an element by name

Tags: jquery, json, traversal, getelementsbyname

I have the following JSON:

> var json = {
>       "system" : {
>           "world" : {
>               "actions" : {
>                   "hello" : {
>                       "src" : "hello world/hello world.js",
>                       "command" : "helloWorld"
>                   }
>               }
>           }
>       }
>   }

I have the following javascript:

> var x = "system";
>   // get the contents of system by doing something like json.getElementByName(x)

How do I get the contents of system using `json` and `x` in jQuery?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use:

```
var x = "system";
json[x];
```

It is a `key/value` system of retrieval, and doesn't need a function call to use it.

Comment: Yes that works unless the label corresponding to the value of "x" is buried deep in the jungle of substructure dangling off the "json" object.

Comment: Perhaps a better example of what you need is `x = "hello"` ? You might want to update your question to reflect that.

Answer (score 4):

Well to my knowledge jQuery doesn't navigate arbitrary objects like that - just the DOM. You could write a little function to do it:

```
function findSomething(object, name) {
  if (name in object) return object[name];
  for (key in object) {
    if ((typeof (object[key])) == 'object') {
      var t = findSomething(object[key], name);
      if (t) return t;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

It should be obvious that I haven't put that function through an elaborate QA process.

Comment: Should check for null on 'object'
...
   `if (object[key] && (typeof (object[key])) == 'object' )`
...

Answer (score 1):

Try using [JSON Path](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/), it is like XPath expression.